# Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 in my laptop;
I have recently downloaded Linux kernel from `git`, but when I am trying to compile it with a make command from the terminal.

It is giving me

```
"error:Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: 
-fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler"
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/issues/92) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/choose-gcc-and-g-version): this error could be the result of multiple gcc versions alternatives.
See "[What exactly does `update-alternatives` do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do)"

Clear them out:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all gcc
$ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all g++
```

Then re-install them, and make sure your gcc and g++ reference the same version.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
sudo update-alternatives --config g++
```

---

Note (March 2017): [doug65536](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1127972/doug65536) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772003/cannot-use-config-cc-stackprotector-strong-fstack-protector-strong-not-support/40772208?noredirect=1#comment72432623_40772208) another case:

> I found a solution to the issue with my nvidia driver package.
>   I had installed a custom build of `binutils` for a `gdb` patch.
>   Forcing it to reinstall `binutils` resolved the issue. It makes no sense, but it worked.

Comment: All of those commands output `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc` or `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for g++`.

Comment: @doug65536 so in your case, you need only to install gcc/g++

Comment: I have gcc, I use it every day. But I found a solution to the issue with my nvidia driver package. I had installed a custom build of binutils for a gdb patch. Forcing it to reinstall binutils resolved the issue. It makes no sense, but it worked.

Comment: @doug65536 Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.