# Linux kernel module programming - Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. I want to start Linux Kernel Module Programming. I have hello.c (simple Hello World module) and Makefile. But, on "make" command, I get error.

I tried [Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772003/cannot-use-config-cc-stackprotector-strong-fstack-protector-strong-not-support) , but it did not work for me.

hello.c

```
/* hello.c − Illustrating the __init, __initdata and __exit macros. */

#include <linux/module.h>
/* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>
/* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>
/* Needed for the macros */

static int hello3_data __initdata = 3;

static int __init hello_3_init(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world %d\n", hello3_data);
  return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_3_exit(void)
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world 3\n");
} 

module_init(hello_3_init);
module_exit(hello_3_exit);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += hello.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

On "make" :-

```
k@k-Inspiron-3542:~/Kernel programs$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/build M=/home/k/Kernel programs modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:662: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `programs'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-27-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Currently, my ubuntu has 4.2 kernel. I even tried this on 3.x kernel, but there was this same error.

Please help me in this. Thanks. :)

Comment: `I tried ... but it did not work for me.` - So, as suggested in the answer to the referenced question, you have updated `binutils` and have installed the only instances of `gcc` and `g++` compilers, right?

Comment: Yes, I did all that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had searched a lot before asking this question, but no solution worked for me. I continued my search and finally, this solution worked for me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/367838/compiling-error-while-installing-realtek-rtl8111e-in-64-bit-13-10-config-x86-x

Strangely, there should be no space(s) in the directory name in which kernel modules are there. So, I removed the space and it worked.

Hope it will help someone in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your file works OK here. With your Makefile, and with the default Makefile:

```
obj-m   := hello.o

KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD     := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

The files `hello.ko, hello.mod.c, hello.mod.o, hello.o, modules.order, Module.symvers` are created. May be install this: `sudo apt install g++ binutils-dev`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have spaces in your compile directory and you're still getting this error, your kernel compilation may be failing because its directory belongs to `root` and you're running as an unprivileged user. Try `sudo make`